# Scrolling/Moving MS chart area to highlighted datapoint when in zoom state

Tags: c#, scroll, mschart

In windows form, I am displaying data in MS Chart from Datagridview.

When selecting an row in the datagridview, I am highlighting the corresponding datapoint in the chart with different color.

When chart is in zoom state , if a datapoint is highlighted newly and if it is not in the visible state, I have to scroll/move the chart to highlighted datapoint.

```
        chart.ChartAreas.Add("LineGraphHistory");
        chart.ChartAreas["LineGraphHistory"].AxisX.Title = "X Axis";
        chart.ChartAreas["LineGraphHistory"].AxisX.MajorGrid.LineColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
        chart.ChartAreas["LineGraphHistory"].AxisX.MajorGrid.LineDashStyle = System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartDashStyle.Dash;
        chart.ChartAreas["LineGraphHistory"].AxisY.Title = "Y Axis";
        chart.ChartAreas["LineGraphHistory"].AxisY.MajorGrid.LineColor = Color.Black;
        chart.ChartAreas["LineGraphHistory"].AxisY.MajorGrid.LineDashStyle = System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartDashStyle.Dash;
        chart.ChartAreas["LineGraphHistory"].BackColor = Color.White;

        chart.ChartAreas["LineGraphHistory"].CursorX.IsUserEnabled = true;

      chart.ChartAreas["LineGraphHistory"].CursorX.IsUserSelectionEnabled = true;
        chart.ChartAreas["LineGraphHistory"].CursorX.Interval = 0;
        chart.ChartAreas["LineGraphHistory"].AxisX.ScaleView.Zoomable = true;
        chart.ChartAreas["LineGraphHistory"].AxisX.ScrollBar.Enabled = true;

        chart.Legends.Add("Legend");
        chart.Legends["Legend"].BorderColor = Color.Tomato;
        chart.DataSource = CSVDataTable;
        chart.ChartAreas["LineGraphHistory"].AxisX.IntervalType = DateTimeIntervalType.Seconds;
        chart.ChartAreas["LineGraphHistory"].AxisX.LabelStyle.Format ="dd-MM-yyyy\n hh:mm:ss"; ;
        chart.Series[s].XValueType =ChartValueType.DateTime ;
        chart.DataBind();
        chart.Update();



       private void cDataGrid_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {
            int nCount = csvDataGrid.SelectedRows.Count;
            if (nCount > 0)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < nCount; i++)
                {
                    int index = csvDataGrid.SelectedRows[i].Index;
                    if (index >= csvDataGrid.Rows.Count-1)
                        return;
                     for (int k = 0; k < chart.Series.Count; k++)
                     {
                         DataPointCollection pr = chart.Series[k].Points;
                         pr[index].MarkerColor = Color.DarkGoldenrod;
                         pr[index].MarkerStyle = MarkerStyle.Star10;
                         pr[index].MarkerSize = 20;
                        // chart.
                       }
                       chart.Update();
                   }
               }
           }
```

How to achieve this?

As Taw suggested I tried to set scaleview position.
I have 10 datapoints. The range of x value of datapoints are 20 to 200. Each x value has equal difference of 20. The view size is 100. In zoom mode, when I scrolling to maximum the x range is 101 to 200 in the view , the last point is displayed as 5th point in the view. Whereas if I use your code to set scaleview position to highlight last datapoint , the x range becomes 180 to 240 and highlighted last datpoint is visible as first range.

Why paintviewmin and paintviewmax values are changing?

The images are 
[image: while scrolling]

[image: while setting scaleview]

Comment: Please read **[ask]** and then supply the code required to create a **[mcve]**

Answer (score 1):

You need to calculate the offset from the `DataPoint dp.XValue`, maybe like this:

```
Axis ax = chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX;
var size = ax.ScaleView.ViewMaximum - ax.ScaleView.ViewMinimum;
ax.ScaleView.Position = dp.XValue - size / 2.0;
```

Example:

[image]

**Update:** When smaller data sets are displayed the automatically added margins mess up the simple calculation above. To avoid this you can add:

```
chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.IsMarginVisible = false;
```

Comment: I tried your code. In the following scenerio I am facing problem.In zoom state when the first datapoint is not in visible state, I am trying to  highlight first point. Now first point got highlighted but the scrollbar position is not zero and first point scaleview position is not correct.

Comment: Define 'correct' for this scenario! It scrolls to the left of the actual data.  You could add checks for this like this `if (ax.ScaleView.Position < s.Points.First().XValue)  ax.ScaleView.Position = s.Points.First().XValue;` and similarily for the other end..

Comment: what I mean is,  your code changes zoom factor and also your code is not matching with scroll position.

Comment: You must be doing something wrong or at least differently than I. It doesn't change the zoom factor it simply centers the view to the selected point, as you can see in the gif.

Comment: I want to show you my project images. In comment section I could not add images. How to show you images?

Comment: I added my images in the question

Comment: I have 10 datapoints. The range of x value of datapoints are 20 to 200. Each x value has equal difference of 20. The view size is 100. In zoom mode, when I scrolling to maximum the x range is 101 to 200 in the view , the last point is displayed as 5th point in the view. Whereas if you use your code to set scaleview position to highlight last datapoint , the x range becomes 180 to 240 and highlighted last datpoint is visible as first range. Why paintviewmin and paintviewmax values are different?

Comment: Can you try my update to see if it changes/improves/solves your issues?